# How to flatten nest Json data with json_normalize

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm trying to import JSON data to Dataframe via json_normalize but cannot get it to work.

My data:

**a** key is same as **c1** key

```
[
  {
    "a": "A1",
    "b": "B1",
    "c": [
      {
        "c1": "C111",
        "c2": "C121",
        "c3": ["C1131","C1132"]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "a": "A2",
    "b": "B2",
    "c": [
      {
        "c1": "C211",
        "c2": "C212",
        "c3": ["C2131","C2132"]
      },
      {
        "c1": "C221",
        "c2": "C222",
        "c3": ["C2231"]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to make a DataFrame like

```
           a     c1(a)      c2                    c3
0         A1      C111    C121     ["C1131","C1132"]
1         A2      C211    C212     ["C2131","C2132"]
2         A2      C221    C222             ["C2231"]
```

When I use json_normalize it shows `ValueError`:

```
entity_df = json_normalize(data, 'c', 'a')

ValueError: Conflicting metadata name a, need distinguishing prefix
```

How should I change the json_normalize parameters?
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

you can try:

```
from collections import defaultdict

norm_data = defaultdict(list)
for item in data:
    for element in item['c']:
        norm_data['a'].append(item['a'])
        for k, v in element.items():
            if k in {'a', 'c1'}:
                norm_data['c1(a)'].append(v)
            else:
                norm_data[k].append(v)

pd.DataFrame(norm_data)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you have already gone through the pain of obscuring your real data, make the mock data having the same features as the real one as well.

Assuming you have this JSON:

```py
json_data =\
[{'a': 'A1',
  'b': 'B1',
  'c': [{'a': 'C111', 'c2': 'C121', 'c3': ['C1131', 'C1132']}]},
 {'a': 'A2',
  'b': 'B2',
  'c': [{'a': 'C211', 'c2': 'C212', 'c3': ['C2131', 'C2132']},
   {'a': 'C221', 'c2': 'C222', 'c3': ['C2231']}]}]
```

You only need one line of code to extract it:

```
pd.json_normalize(json_data, 'c', ['a', 'b'], record_prefix='data.')
```

Result:

```
  data.a data.c2         data.c3   a   b
0   C111    C121  [C1131, C1132]  A1  B1
1   C211    C212  [C2131, C2132]  A2  B2
2   C221    C222         [C2231]  A2  B2
```

The `record_prefix='data.'` is what the `ValueError: Conflicting metadata name a, need distinguishing prefix` error message meant.

Answer (score 0):

```
data = [
  {
    "a": "A1",
    "b": "B1",
    "c": [
      {
        "c1": "C111",
        "c2": "C121",
        "c3": ["C1131","C1132"]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "a": "A2",
    "b": "B2",
    "c": [
      {
        "c1": "C211",
        "c2": "C212",
        "c3": ["C2131","C2132"]
      },
      {
        "c1": "C221",
        "c2": "C222",
        "c3": ["C2231"]
      }
    ]
  }
]
pd.io.json.json_normalize(data,"c", ['a', 'b',])
```

Output:

```
    c1      c2      c3              a   b
0   C111    C121    [C1131, C1132]  A1  B1
1   C211    C212    [C2131, C2132]  A2  B2
2   C221    C222    [C2231]         A2  B2
```

Comment: Still got `Conflicting metadata name a, need distinguishing prefix `, the 'c1' and 'a' is same str, how shoul I add prefix?

Comment: Thanks for helping me, I finally got the solution with adding `record_prefix='_'`

Comment: It working for me fine, are you sure you have all the details included or there is something messing?