# Pandas - Flatten irregular nested JSON

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have following JSON object and try to convert it into a DataFrame.

Data:

```
{
  "data": {
    "docs": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "col1": "foo",
        "col2": "123",
        "list": ["foo barr, fooo"]
      },
      {
         "id": "2",
        "col1": "abc",
        "col2": "321",
        "list": ["lirum epsum"]
      },
      {
         "id": "3",
        "col1": "foo",
        "col2": "123",
        "list": null
   
      }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Ideally the list column should contain of **strings** instead of lists and look like this:

```
id  col1    col2    list
1   foo     123     'foo barr, fooo'
2   abc     321     'lirum epsum'
3   foo     123      NaN
```

Following approach is throwing an exception (TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable):

```
with open(path_to_json, encoding='utf-8') as json_file:
    q= json.load(json_file)
    df = json_normalize(q['data'], record_path=['docs', 'list'])
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to flatten nest Json data with json\_normalize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57448823/how-to-flatten-nest-json-data-with-json-normalize)

Comment: Your so-called JSON "object" (which is really a string), has extra `},` characters.

Comment: The problem is that the column 'list' is saved as the datatype list and should be saved as String.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot add comment (yet) to complete  the answer above  but you can convert your column list to string using this code

```
df['list']=df['list'].apply(lambda x: str(x).strip('[\']'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
json = {
  "data": {
    "docs": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "col1": "foo",
        "col2": "123",
        "list": ["foo barr, fooo"]
      },
      {
         "id": "2",
        "col1": "abc",
        "col2": "321",
        "list": ["lirum epsum"]
      },
      {
         "id": "3",
        "col1": "foo",
        "col2": "123",
        "list": np.nan
   
      },
      
    ]
  }
}
pd.DataFrame(json["data"]["docs"]).set_index("id")
```

gives you

```
    id  col1    col2    list
    1   foo     123     [foo barr, fooo]
    2   abc     321     [lirum epsum]
    3   foo     123     NaN
```

Comment: You can then use [`.str.join(', ')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.join.html) to convert the `list` column into a string

Comment: It's still in brackets and saved as a list